# .Add usage in 2 dimensional dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

Hi I am working with a dictionary that looks like this:

`Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, char>> VisDIC = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, char>>();`

And I was wondering how I would go about adding a Char to the inner dictionary. I can acess it quite simply by just doing (same as with a 2d list):

`VisDIC[Xpos][Ypos]`

But something like this wont work:

`VisDIC[Xpos][Ypos].Add(Xpos, Char)`

Nor this:

`VisDIC.Add(Xpos[Ypos], Char)`

I need to use the Add function since I lack keys in the dictionaries, Ie. this wont work:

`VisDIC[Xpos][Ypos] = Char`

So either  I have to use `Add` in some way or find another way to add values/keys to the inner dictionary. All help and insight is appreciated!

Comment: `VisDIC[Xpos][Ypos] = Char` _does_ add the key `Ypos` to an inner dictionary if that key does not already exist. It is effectively an "add or update" method.

Comment: This is a bad design. You should not have a `Dictionary` in another `Dictionary`. First you need to check if the first `int` key exist, if not you need to create a new `Dictionary<int,char>` then you need to get that `Dictionary` within the first and then try to add new key in that one. Instantiation madness ahead. Ask yourself if you really need that structure ? why wouldn't a 2D array of char do the work ? Why would a `Struct` with `X` and `Y` property not be enough for a single key `Dictionary` ?

Comment: @Franck  : What is wrong with a dictionary in a dictionary.  It is often used.

Comment: Try following : Dictionary<Dictionary<int, char> firstDict = VisDIC[123];
firstDict.Add(456, 'z');

Comment: @jdweng i mentioned it in my comment being a instance madness. Check first key, if doesn't exist create it with new dictionary instance, then check for key if doesn't exist create, if not update. A composite key dictionary is a single check. That is a perfect case of a composite key instead of nested keys.

Comment: @Franck I have already tried Arrays and Lists and I have come to the realization that dictionaries are the best option for what I want to do. They work well when you have an unidentified limit to them and large sections without anything in it.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay You were right, it was my fault for not making sure the rest of my code worked, instead of the error being the XPOS it was the YPOS that had nothing to do with this problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Grusen i said nothing against `Dictionary`, there is just other option than nested ones. Something like `public struct CompositeKey { public int X; public int Y; }` and a dictionary as a single level like `Dictionary<CompositeKey,char>` is a less complicated and more representative.

Comment: That is not "two-dimensional", that is a _dictionary of dictionaries_, which is tantamount to the difference between a _two-dimensional array_ and a _jagged array_ (array of arrays).

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary of dictionaries extension method for dual-level Add.

```cs
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static void Add2D<A, B, C>(this Dictionary<A, Dictionary<B, C>> me, A a, B b, C val)
    {
        Dictionary<B, C> child;
        if (!me.TryGetValue(a, out child)) {
            child = new Dictionary<B, C>();
            me.Add(a, child);
        }
        child.Add(b, val);
    }
}
```

Use like this:

```
VisDIC.Add2D(1, 2, 'X')
```